# ASP.NET MVC PresentationModel Binding to ComboBoxes stays empty

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, combobox, viewmodel, model-binding

Hello I'm learning to program MVC style in ASP.NET. I'm trying to populate a combobox with my PresentationModel, somehow it stays empty.

I'm using the ASP tag-helpers:

View (Index.cshtml)

```
@model Week3_oef2_ITPro.PresentationModel.PMRegistration

<h2>New Registration</h2>
<h4>Registration</h4>
<form asp-controller="Register" asp-action="" method="post">
   <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Organization</td>
            <td class="form-group">
                <select asp-for="OrgId.Id" asp-items="@Model.Org" class="form-group" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr><td><input type="submit" /></td></tr>
   </table>
</form>
```

PresentationModel (PMRegistration.cs)

```
public class PMRegistration
{
    public Organization OrgId { get; set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> Org { get; set; }
}
```

Model (Organization.cs)

```
public class Organization
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

}
```

**Data** (Where all the objects are initialized)

```
public class Data
{
    private static List<Session> sessions = new List<Session>();
    private static List<Organization> organizations = new List<Organization>();
    private static List<Device> devices = new List<Device>();

    static Data()
    {
        organizations.Add(new Organization() { Id = 1, Name = "Howest" });
        organizations.Add(new Organization() { Id = 2, Name = "Vives" });
        organizations.Add(new Organization() { Id = 3, Name = "HoGent" });
        organizations.Add(new Organization() { Id = 4, Name = "HoLimburg" });
        organizations.Add(new Organization() { Id = 4, Name = "De blauwe smurfen" });

        devices.Add(new Device() { Id = 1, Name = "Laptop" });
        devices.Add(new Device() { Id = 2, Name = "Tablet" });
        devices.Add(new Device() { Id = 3, Name = "Apple Watch" });
    }

    public static List<Device> GetDevices()
    {
        return devices;
    }

    public static List<Organization> GetOrganizations()
    {
        return organizations;
    }
}
```

Controller (RegisterController.cs)

```
public class RegisterController : Controller
{
    // GET: /<controller>/
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        PMRegistration pm = new PMRegistration();
        pm.OrgId = new Organization();
        pm.Org = ConverToListItems(Data.GetOrganizations());
        return View(pm);
    }
    #region methodes
    private List<SelectListItem> ConverToListItems(List<Organization> data)
    {
        List<SelectListItem> items = new List<SelectListItem>();
        foreach (var item in data)
        {
            items.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = item.Name, Value = item.Id.ToString() });
        }
        return items;
    }
    #endregion

}
```

Comment: where is the code for `Index` action method where you are passing an object of `PMRegistration` class ?

Comment: Forgot to show my Controller, one sec

Comment: @Shyju it's added now, I forgot sorry

Comment: It is a silly problem with your html markup :) See the answer posted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your HTML markup for the SELECT element is wrong. The SELECT element requires a closing tag.

It should be

```
<select asp-for="OrgId.Id" asp-items="@Model.Org" class="form-group"></select>
```

Comment: Oh God, I just wasted 4 hours in that. Thank you, I'll be able to sleep now :) Have a good day